# how to change the ImageButton's image when it is pressed and released?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I want that in my android application, the `ImageButton` change its image when it is pressed and released, and when it is pressed released again, the image for `ImageButton` will be changed back , how to do that?

Answer (score 8):

create a selector (it is an xml file)  put in drawable folder. and in xml five path of that xml instaed of actual image `android:background="@drawable/imageselector"` or in program also you can get the same using `imageview.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.imageselector)`

Following is my selector
**imageselector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/arow_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/arow_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/arow_selected" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/arow_unselect" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 7):

use **selector** for this...here is a link for this..
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Image View for the same:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_new_delete0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

Code behind:

```
ImageView _iv1 = _activity.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.iv1);

        _iv1.Touch += (object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e) => {
            if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                _iv1.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_new_delete);
                //Do the task when button is pressed
            }
            else if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            {
               _iv1.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_new_delete0);
               //do the task when button is released
            }
        };
```